# How do I copy certain elements of an array to a location before it in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a CSV file, `Original.csv`, where I am checking all the rows to see if the element in the 28th column is empty. If it is not empty, I want to copy the 28th, 31st, 33rd and 34th elements to their previous positions; if it is empty, then I don't want to do anything. And then, I want to store the content in a new file, `New.csv`. This is my code:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.open('New.csv', "wb") do |csv|
   CSV.foreach('Original.csv') do |row|
       if row[28]!=nil
            row[27]=row[28]
            row[30]=row[31]
            row[32]=row[33]
            row[33]=row[34]
        end
        csv<<row
   end
end
```

But, the program copies the columns without checking the condition! What is wrong?

**EDIT:** I figured out the bug. Turns out, what I thought was empty, i.e., `""`, was actually a space, i.e., `" "`. This stupid thing took 4 hours of my time! So, if anyone is facing a similar issue, the takeaway is - what something appears as is not necessarily what it actually is. So beware. And one way to do that is not open the file in MS Excel, but rather in some primitive application like Notepad, Sublime, etc.

Comment: Looks good. The question is what's "empty"? `nil` or `''`?

Comment: Huh? Is there any difference?

Comment: In Ruby, the empty string `''` does not compare equal to `nil`. They are even different classes.

Comment: 1 more thing, 28th element is row[27]. Please make sure again

Comment: @shirakia Yeah, I have kept track of that.

Comment: @undur_gongor Oh! Ok, so I ran the code with the single quotes now. Still no change, identical result.

Comment: @undur_gongor Are you there? I tried with double quotes too. Same result.

Comment: Try changing "if row[28]!=nil" to "if row[28].empty?"

Comment: @vlasits Done. Same result.

Comment: So, what does row[28] actually contain in the situation where it is returning the wrong result?  Put `puts row[28]` in your code.

Comment: @vlasits Ok, I put `puts` and checked what row[28] displays. It displays what was basically row[29] - i.e., it copied everything from the next row without checking the `if` condition. I don't know what sorcery is this!

Comment: I'm in a chat channel:  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93596/row28

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say " it copied everything from the next row without checking the if condition."  I think it checked the condition and evaluated it as true.  I think you need to figure out how to write the if statement so that it is actually checking what you want it to check.

Comment: @vlasits You're right. It turns out that what I thought was empty, i.e., `""`, was actually a space, i.e., `" "`. Funny how this stupid thing took 2 hours of my time.

Comment: I modified my answer.  I think it deals with your question correctly.  Mind accepting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly looks as though `if row[28]!=nil` is evaluating as false when you don't expect it to.  There are a few possible reasons for that:

As commenter undur_gongor wrote:
"In Ruby, the empty string '' does not compare equal to nil. They are even different classes"

**Therefore**: 
`if row[28]!=nil` will evaluate to `true` unless row[28] actually contains the `nil` object.  If it contains an empty string (e.g. `''` or `""`) it will evaluate to `false`.

**Solution**:
Make sure that your "if" statement is actually evaluating as you expect it to.  My guess is that you want something like `row[28].empty?` or `row[28].strip.empty?` if it turns out the problem is you have a few white spaces.

Comment: Tried that too, good sir, as I said in one of the comments. Still the same result.